# Manipulating Camera Colors and Displaying it with Android Studios

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, android-camera2

I am currently working on an application in android studios that messes with the colors of live camera feed from a phones camera. For example, I may want to filter out all the reds, or maybe I want to make displayed camera image black-and-white.

However, I haven't really found much on *how* to do this. I've found tutorials on using both the deprecated Camera class and the android.hardware.camera2 class. My preferred sample code was for camera2, found directly [here](https://github.com/MrTillis/Camera2Basic/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic) (takes you directly to Java class files, not whole project).

So does anyone know how to use camera2 to do what I want? Do I need to use the deprecated class Camera instead? My idea is that I need to have an activity that has the main job of displaying images, and behind the scenes the phone camera is running, sending the image (in whatever format, Bitmap) to have the colors messed with (by some code I will make), which then sends the image to be displayed in the main activity.

So that is three main pieces: (1) Camera to Bitmap, to get what is currently seen by the phone Camera and store it in code; (2) mess with the colors of the Bitmap to distort the current view in my desired way; and (3) then a way of taking the resulting distorted view and displaying that on the screen. Of course, as mentioned, it's the first and last of the three just mentioned that I really need help with.

Please let me know what other details will be helpful to know about.

Comment: I removed the `BufferedImage` tag, as you can't use that class on Android. The Android equivalent is `Bitmap`.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. I've edited my answer as well.